# Is there a way to pass variable itself(not the value) as argument in Python?

Tags: python

I have a class with several data member and I want to write a function to compare different data member depend on the input of that function. Is there a way to pass variable itself into the function?

For example:

```
class someClass:
    self.a = 1
    self.b = 1.1
    self.c = 1

def someFunction(x, lt, var):  #lt is a list of someClass, var is the variable I want to choose to compare with
    for v in lt:    
        if x.var < v.var:
            ...
```

I think there must be some distinct characteristic between same variable in deferent instance, but not sure what it is.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it's probably not what you want.

If you find yourself accessing things by (string) names a lot, you're looking for a dictionary. Rather than having three separate fields `self.a`, `self.b`, and `self.c`, consider having just one: `self.data`.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 1.1,
            "c": 1,
        }

def some_function(x, some_class_instances, var):
    for y in some_class_instances:    
        if x.data[var] < y.data[var]:
            ...
```

Generally, you want to use dictionaries if you want this form of access.

*That being said*, what you asked for can be done. Pretty much anything can be done in Python, with enough effort. To be clear, I strongly recommend using a dictionary, but for completeness, [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) is a built-in Python function that performs dot-notation style access with a string argument. This won't just get slots on `__dict__`; it'll also catch `property`s, other descriptors, or anything else; it's literally equivalent to using a dot to access the field, with all the caveats that come with that.

```
def some_function(x, some_class_instances, var):
    for y in some_class_instances:    
        if getattr(x, var) < getattr(y, var):
            ...
```

Comment: I see!! `getattr` is what I've been looking for!! Thanks a lot! But I would try the dictionary later, I think it is better

Comment: Is this a Python only thing? I don't think c/c++ have something similar?

Comment: It's a reflection feature. Lots of dynamic languages, like Python, Javascript, and Ruby, have reflection. It's less common in compiled languages. There's no way to do this in C or C++.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much ~